# Finding maximum likelihood solution for mean when data is given which share the same mean but have different variance

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, gaussian-mixture-distribution

I have some 'X sample points say (x1,x2,x3 ...) each of the samples form a Gaussian distribution with mean 'm' and variance v1,v2, ... All the distributions have the same mean but differ in variance. I need to find maximum likelihood for 'm'.

I understand that I have to compute the log(prod (Gaussian equation)) and then partially differentiate wrt m and v and equate them to 0 to get equations for each. But as the v is not constant and becomes a summation I am unable to get an equation for m.

Comment: Are the variances known? And do you know which points were sampled from each distribution?

Comment: nope that information is not given.

Comment: we are given n = 7 samples {x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7} each form a gaussian distribution with mean m and variance v1. Note all distributions share the mean it is m for each of them, but have unknown unique variances. what is the MLE for m? is the exact question.